# How does Read-Only field level security affects Apex and Workflows

Tags: apex, workflow, security, field-level-security, read-only

Let's say I have a Profile in the system which has a particular Field of an Object set as `Read-Only`.

How does this affect my Apex code and Workflows if they are executed by a User with this Profile? Will Apex and Workflows be able to edit the `Read-Only` field, or will it throw an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apex and Workflows function independently of field level security; see the documentation for [considerations for workflows](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&language=en) and [Field level security](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_fls.htm).

So Apex code and workflows will be able to read and write to fields that could be hidden or read only for the user.

To be abundantly clear, using `with sharing` on your class definition does not change anything about this. That annotation only limits the rows a user can see, not the columns. Also; see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)

Comment: Does your answer apply if I set the `with sharing` on my Apex class?

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer that specifically.